# Fire NSTimer from background

Tags: ios, iphone, background, nstimer

I know there are some questions on this here but my problem is a bit different from them which is why i am asking this question. At the moment i have a `NSTimer` which is firing every 2 minutes. When the timer was fired there is a 25% chance that my method will be called (it is for a game). For example my `NSTimer` fires, now a random number is generated from 0-3. If this random number equals 0 then my method should be called. The exact same behavior i'd like to have when my app goes into background mode. When the `NSTimer` is fired the random number should be generated and if this number equals to 0 then a UILocalNotification should be posted.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
    - (IBAction)toggleBattleMode:(id)sender
{
    if (self.battleMode == NO)
    {
        self.battleMode = YES;
        battleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120 target:self selector:@selector(pushBattle:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self performSelector:@selector(fireTimer:) withObject:self afterDelay:10];
        [sender setEnabled:YES];
        [sender setAlpha:1.0];
    }
    else
    {
        [battleTimer invalidate];
        battleTimer = nil;
        [sender setEnabled:NO];
        [sender setAlpha:0.5];
    }
}


- (void)fireTimer:(id)sender
{
    [battleTimer fire];
}


- (IBAction)pushBattle:(id)sender
{
    int randNum = rand() % (4);
    if(randNum == 0) {
    NSArray *boundingBox = [dataHelper getBoundingBox:map.userLocation.coordinate];
    NSArray *phrases = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"water", @"forest", @"wood", @"mountain", @"graveyard", @"river", nil];

    [self.locArray removeAllObjects];

    if (![self queue])
    {
        [self setQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < phrases.count; i++)
    {
        NSURL *url = [dataHelper getURLForSpecialPhrase:phrases[i] withBoundingBox:boundingBox];

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setTag:i];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [[self queue] addOperation:request];
    }
    [self.queue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:0 context:NULL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not do this when your app is running in the background. What you could do is to determine all the 2 minute interval random numbers beforehand (for a certain period of time, say 2 hours) when the app is going to background mode, and schedule local timers for all the times the random number is 0.

I don't think users will be happy if they get spammed with local notifications every 8 minutes while your app is running in the background, by the way ...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Yeah when i see it written it feels definitely not right. I will think about it again. But if i want to implement i'll know how. Thanks